# Strange behaviour after installing Firebase tools

Tags: android, firebase

After installing Firebase tools on my Android app, I found some strange behavior and I`m in need of help.

What is going on. App freezes on first screen, showing "not responding alert". There is no special things about this first activity, just several buttons in recyclerView.

Strange thing is, that on my own device there is no problems, as well as on emulators of any types. I got information from users and from pre-release Google tests. May be someone faced similar problems and willing to share aid.

Here is dependencies

```
dependencies {
compile files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3.jar')
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.4.0'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
```

}

What else info needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that problem was on devices with no Google Play services installed. With last update, from 21 of September, problem is now gone.

Just update

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.6.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0' add this in gradle.

As well try with replacing appcompat-v7:24.2.1 and other libraries to 23.1.1

Answer (score 0):

In build.gradle file under your app folder add the code after dependencies

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

then in the project level build.gradle file add the following code

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```